# PHALCON SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: php, model-view-controller, phalcon

This is ***PHALCON*** php related issue.

I tried to create new project with PHALCON by doing this.

```
    # phalcon project blog
    Phalcon DevTools (2.0.1)
    Success: Controller "index" was successfully created.  
    Success: Project 'blog' was successfully created.
```

I created the controller

```
# cd blog
# phalcon controller poll
phalcon controller poll
Phalcon DevTools (2.0.1)
Success: Controller "poll" was successfully created.
```

and created my model, I edited first my config.php for the mysql db settings

```
    # phalcon model polls
    Phalcon DevTools (2.0.1)
    Success: Model "polls" was successfully created.
```

i edited the poll controller

```
public function indexAction()
{
   $this->view->polls = Polls::find(); //added to the original source...
}
```

and created my viewer as simple as

```
  <h1>Polls</h1>
```

When I test it I got the error

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I posted this earlier and someone advice me that services.php#56 so I rectified it by entering the advice script.

```
//$di->set('db', function () use ($config) {
//    return new DbAdapter($config->database->toArray());
//});

//But recommed setting like

$di->set(
    'db',
    function () use ($config) {
        return new DbAdapter([
            'host'     => $config->database->mysql->host,
            'username' => $config>database->mysql->username,
            'password' => $config->database->mysql->password,
            'dbname'   => $config->database->mysql->dbname,
            'options'  => array(
                \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES ' . $config->database->mysql->charset
            )
        ]);
    },
    true // shared
);
```

After applying it I just encountered similar error

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

I need help...  I want to fly with PHALCON....

Comment: What does your db config look like? If you have `localhost` set for the host config setting try changing it to `127.0.0.1` or `0.0.0.0`

Comment: Yous configuration seems to be corrupted or set to PHP in wrong way. This error happent if standard connection was ommited and socket connection was choosen. Provide us more var_dump's and config structure.

Comment: When you use docker-compose / named docker services you can probably also add the name of that service in the place of localhost / hostname .

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the posts, but I guess I missed somewhere else in the installation.

=> What I did is delete all phalcon, and then reinstall phalcon and devtools, after that, my phalcon is working fine now.

Thanks for the support, thanks **honerlawd**.

Im now flying with phalcon, I am done with my first crud-blog.  I am starting a more complex application.